# Survival function in terms of the hazards

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Let $T$ be a discrete random variable assuming values $x_1<x_2<\ldots$ with probability $f(x_i) = \text{Pr}\left\{T=x_i\right\}$. Show that the survival function $S(t)=\prod_{i:x_i\leq t}(1-\lambda_i)$ and $f(x_i) = \lambda_i\prod_{j=1}^{i-1} (1-\lambda_j)$ where $$\lambda_i = \text{Pr}\left\{ T=x_i|T\geq x_i\right\} = \dfrac{\text{Pr}\left\{ T=x_i\right\}}{\text{Pr}\left\{ T\geq x_i\right\}} = \dfrac{f(x_i)}{S(x_i-)}$$ the "hazard" and $$ S(t-) = \lim_{h\downarrow 0} \text{Pr}\left\{ T>t-h\right\} = \text{Pr}\left\{ T\geq t\right\}$$

Can you guys give me some ideas? It seems baffling to me that the survival function can be written as something involving the product of the probability mass function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show that
$$
1-\lambda_i=\frac{P(T\geq x_{i+1})}{P(T\geq x_i)}
$$
for all $i$. Then if $t>0$ and $k$ is the index such that $x_k\leq t<x_{k+1}$ you have to show that
$$
\prod_{i:x_i\leq t}(1-\lambda_i)=S(x_k)=S(t).
$$

Comment: clever, I see that the $S(x_i)$'s will cancel out leaving you with $S(x_k)$ (Since $S(x_1-)=1$). Thank you!

Comment: Indeed. You're very welcome.